# Pastebin API: Getting Unlisted Paste Always

Tags: python, api, private, paste, pastebin

I want to make a public paste using pastebin API but i'm always getting my paste as unlisted

here is my code:

```
from socket import *


skt=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
skt.connect(("pastebin.com", 80))


req="api_dev_key=MyAPIKey&api_option=paste&api_paste_code=TEST&api_paste_private=0&api_paste_name=TEST\
&api_paste_expire_date=N&api_paste_format=python"
request="POST /api/api_post.php HTTP/1.1\r\n\
Host: pastebin.com\r\n\
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\
Content-Length: "+str(len(req))+"\r\n\r\n"

skt.send(request+req);
try:
    print(skt.recv(2024));
except:
    print("[-] Timeout")

skt.close()
```

api_paste_private=0 for public paste

Answer (score 2):

duplicate content gets auto unlisted. also certain keywords will force auto unlisted.